# Wordpress remove ?id= from custom plugin url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a page url like

```
https://names.example.com/name/?id=سالم
```

help me to create htaccess or add_rewrite_rule() Function so my url be

```
https://names.example.com/name/سالم/
```

am use

```
$mn =  $_GET['id'];
$getmn = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$tablename." WHERE name='".$mn."' ")
```

What should I do to get rid of the ?id= tags following my posts URLs?

thanks